# New iOS app version and 64-bit support

Tags: ios, architecture, app-store, 64-bit

I have an iOS app already available in App Store. Until now, I've built this app with these settings:

- Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
- Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s

I had several versions approved this way, the last one in July, and the app works fine even in iPhone 5S in 32 bits mode.

However, I have recently read this ([App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1))

> Note about 64-bit architecture
>
> An app extension target must include the arm64 architecture in its
> Architectures build settings or it will be rejected by the App Store.
> Xcode includes this architecture with its “Standard architectures”
> setting when you create a new app extension target.
>
> If your containing app target links to an embedded framework, the app
> must also include the arm64 architecture or it will be rejected by the
> App Store.

Does it mean that, if I submit now a new version of my app, it must be built for $(ARCHS_STANDARD) or it will be rejected otherwise? Or having setting `arm64 armv7 armv7s` as valid architectures will be still enough? Is there any due date for supporting 64 bits?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For iOS 8 Apple will probably make 64 bit mandatory, so it is a good time to upgrade your project.

Comment: Even I am facing the same dilemma. Please let me know if anyone knows about it.